# Is it possible to run PPPoE and dot1Q protocol simultaneously on a cisco router?

Tags: cisco, switch, router, trunk, optical

So here's a problem I need to solve and I am having issues researching for an answer.

I have an optical cable that's coming in through SFP and it is forced to be connected to a switch before going to the router. This link is actually a trunk and it holds a few VLANs. The problem is, the switch will take this link and connect to the router with PPPoE, and then the router will have a connection going back into the switch with dot1Q (for VLANs).

So the current scenario is this:

Switch receives an optical trunk link, switch is connected to router (PPPoE), router connects back to switch (dot1Q) in order to distribute to the rest of the network.

So is it possible? If I am not mistaken, the router on hand is the Cisco 1800 router.

And if this is not possible, any suggestions on how to deal with this? The router is not able to take the optical trunk link, which is why this whole problem is created.

[image]

Comment: You are trying to make a link be both a layer-2 link (trunk), and a layer-3 routed link. You need to have one or the other.

Normally PPP is not run on a LAN, and a switch will not have a routed link unless it is a layer-3 switch. You need to give us more information. For instance, what are the device models and the reason you are trying to do this.

Comment: As said before I believe it's the 1800 series routers, can't get my hands on the switch models unfortunately. As for why... There's a dorm that needs some work and they are changing their ISP, the new one comes in with an optical cable that has trunks for each floor of the building. Problem is, the router can't take that optical cable, only the switch can.

Comment: The switch that will receive the link is definitely nothing fancy-ish like a 2960 series etc... it's older than that, but still solid.

Comment: I still don't understand the reason for PPP. You should be able to run a trunk link. It may be that the router model doesn't have any built-in fiber ports. You could use a distribution switch, and connect it to the router with copper, but I just don't think you want to run PPP. Unfortunately, questions about residential networking are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not for me to decide... They already did the contract...  And no other equipment (swtiches or otherwise) will be brought in. Even if it is off topic, I would appreciate any help. I am still a junior network enginner, just started recently after finishing my cisco academy. So my knowledge is still small.

Comment: voted to reopen. I don't see what's off topic here. It should work provide the PPPOE connection is in a dedicated VLAN  (SFP plugged in a port in access mode for the vlan) and the PPP  configuration on the router is done under this vlan interface.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding or maybe explained it wrong, just to be sure: an optical link is going into the switch, it's a trunk. So that specific port has to be a trunk port. And the link from the switch to the router also has to be a trunk (since there are 5 vlans). https://i.gyazo.com/8fbf95292c463d1a95660306c2dca504.png

Comment: that image is a simple representation of the issue. That same single port has to run PPPoE and at the same time dot1Q for the returning traffic. So I don't understand how I would put a port in access mode.

Comment: Ok I see but surely the PPPOE connection is encapsulated in one of the 5 VLAN ? if so then you have to perform the PPPOE configuration under the vlan interface for that vlan on the router

Comment: @JFL, it is for a dormitory (residential) network, and those are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: PPPoE is a layer-3 link, but you need a layer-2 (trunk) link to the switch. You just configure the VLANs on the router subinterfaces for the physical interface. You may need PPPoE to the ISP, but you really don't run that in your LAN. You select one router interface to be the PPPoE interface to your ISP (if needed), and another router interface to be the trunk to the LAN.

Comment: My ISP do the same,it is run accept PPPOE on specific VLAN so to connect the router to that ISP you need to define subinterface on the router tagged for that VLAN and define the PPPOE config on this sub interface.
I think in case you put switch in middle the switch ports should be truncks and you need to define the WAN VLAN on teh switch.

Comment: @RonMaupin In the USA, "dormitory" pretty much always means a building on a university campus where students and/or faculty live, and generally internet is provided by campus IT, so to me (as an American) the word "dormitory" explicitly means it's either a business network or the asker is trying to circumvent their campus IT department to do something they shouldn't, but it doesn't sound like that. Perhaps "dormitory" means something different in other flavors of English (maybe it means "apartment"?). Chessbrain, what country are you in and what type of building is this network in?

Comment: As an American, that is my understanding of a dormitory. It has long been established on this site, that dormitories, like in a university, are residences, and are off-topic here. It is not something that I made up. This is something that should probably be hashed out on [meta].

Comment: @RonMaupin Oh, interesting. I guess it's like a business residence and maybe we don't want to get bogged down in questions from apartment managers and landlords and so on? My apologies.

Comment: To answer the question... I live in a country called Bosnia, and this dormitory belongs to the government (at least you can say it is), it is more along the lines of an institution than a simple residence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that your question is a bit more clear, you con connect the switch to the router on one of the copper interfaces. Just configure the link between the router and the switch as a trunk link. If you need PPPoE on one of the VLANs, then set up PPPoE on the subinterface for that VLAN. Just don't run your internal VLANs out to the ISP.

The drawing is a pretty poor way of doing things because you have no firewall, and your network equipment is exposed to the public Internet.

Just because the ISP connects to your switch via fiber, that does not mean that your switch must connect to the router via fiber. The switch really doesn't care which interface is connected to either the ISP, the router, or the hosts. As far as the switch is concerned, the router is just another host, but one connected via a trunk, and you can run a trunk on any of the switch interfaces, as long as the device on the other end of the link understands VLAN tags.

Comment: The intention could be to put a firewall "downstream" of the router.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I actually researched a lot that day and came upon a partial solution. With what you said it all makes sense now :D Thanks!